# ReactJs : useRef current getting null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am trying to turnoff **camera and flashlight** when the component gets **unmount** , I am using react hook I have two function **startCamera() and stopCamera()** , I am calling startcamera when the component gets mount and stop camera when component gets unmount.
But its showing me error when stopCamera is called while unmounting
[image]

i have created an another button to test if StopCamera() working and i found **its working** , **but i want to call the function when component is getting unmounted**

my code:

**CameraScreen.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function CameraScreen() {
  const videoElement = useRef(null);
  const [facingMode, setFacingMode] = useState("environment");
  const handleFacingModeToggle = () => {
    stopCamera();
    facingMode === "environment"
      ? setFacingMode("user")
      : setFacingMode("environment");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    // const getUserMedia = async () => {
    //   try {
    //     const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    //       video: true
    //     });
    //     videoElement.current.srcObject = stream;
    //   } catch (err) {
    //     console.log(err);
    //   }
    // };
    // getUserMedia();
    startCamera();
    return function cleanup() {
      stopCamera();
    };
  }, []);

  const stopCamera = () =>
    videoElement.current.srcObject &&
    videoElement.current.srcObject.getTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());
  function startCamera() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          video: { facingMode: facingMode },
          width: { ideal: 1280 },
          height: { ideal: 720 }
        })
        .then(function (stream) {
          if (videoElement.current) videoElement.current.srcObject = stream;
          const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];

          //Create image capture object and get camera capabilities
          const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track);
          const photoCapabilities = imageCapture
            .getPhotoCapabilities()
            .then(() => {
              //todo: check if camera has a torch

              //let there be light!

              track.applyConstraints({
                advanced: [{ torch: true }]
              });
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          alert("Please check your device permissions");
          console.log("Something went wrong!");
          console.log(error);
        });
      if (videoElement.current)
        videoElement.current.onloadeddata = function () {
          if (window.NativeDevice)
            window.NativeDevice.htmlCameraReadyToRecord(true);
        };
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <video
        autoPlay={true}
        ref={videoElement}
        style={{
          minHeight: "67.82vh",
          maxHeight: "67.82vh",
          maxWidth: "100%",
          minWidth: "100%"
        }}
        className="border-3rem bg-[#666]"
      ></video>

      <button onClick={stopCamera}> stopCamera</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import CameraScreen from "./cameraScreen";
export default function App() {
  const [switchS, setSwitchS] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="" onClick={() => setSwitchS(!switchS)} value="switch">
        switch
      </button>
      
      {switchS && <CameraScreen />}
      {!switchS && "Blank Screen"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

PS: the above code working at :https://5t2to.csb.app/

codesandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-fast-5t2to?file=/src/cameraScreen.js

Comment: Change the stopCamera method like this: `const stopCamera = () => videoElement?.current?.srcObject && videoElement.current.srcObject.getTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `useLayoutEffect` hook. It works just before unmounting, like `componentWillUnmount`.

Here is an example to that
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/random.js

You can go to https://ikqdn.csb.app/rand in `sandbox browser` and check the `console` on clicking `to home` button.

**You can see the difference in working while `unmounting` of both `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect`**

---

It preserves `ref.current`, so what you can do is, you can pass ref.current in the function that you are calling `just before unmounting`, to prevent ref to the `dom elment`.

Answer (score 1):

It took a bit of debugging/sleuthing to find the issue. So even though you have a ref attached to the `video` element, when the component is unmounted the ref is still mutated and becomes undefined. The solution is to save a reference to the current `videoElement` ref value and use this in a cleanup function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  startCamera();

  const ref = videoElement.current;

  return () => {
    ref.srcObject.getTracks().forEach((t) => t.stop());
  };
}, []);
```

[image: Edit reactjs-useref-current-getting-null]

Answer (score 1):

Simply add useLayoutEffect to stop camera

```
useEffect(() => {
    // const getUserMedia = async () => {
    //   try {
    //     const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    //       video: true
    //     });
    //     videoElement.current.srcObject = stream;
    //   } catch (err) {
    //     console.log(err);
    //   }
    // };
    // getUserMedia();
    startCamera();
  }, []);
useLayoutEffect(()=>()=>{
   stopCamera();
},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change `useEffect()` to `useLayoutEffect()`and it will works like a charm.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
     const ref = videoElement;
     console.log(ref);
     startCamera();
  return function cleanup() {
     stopCamera();
  };
}, []);
```

sanbox link :- https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-murdock-by5tc?file=/src/cameraScreen.js:415-731